# How fast does the Discord orb travel?

Tags: overwatch

As Zenyatta, one key way you help your team is by placing orbs of discord so enemies take increased damage. But I'm greedy, and often I want to discord orb someone I have lined up in my sights. Occasionally, however, this happens after I've already started charging up my alt fire.

You can't launch an orb of discord while the alt fire is charged up. But you can launch an orb of discord immediately after the alt fire is released, and both your alt fire and the orb of discord have some travel time to the target.

Does the orb of discord travel fast enough to boost the damage from your alt fire if you cast it *after* you've released the alt fire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information online doesn't seem to exist regarding the flight speed of both his Orbs of Destruction (weapon) and the Orb of Discord that is his debuff.

To test this out I started a custom game vs me and a few easy-level Bastion bots.   The testing stage was Hanamura, with me on defenders, waiting close to the gate, with the Bastions coming out of spawn as normal.

I tested this by charging up the orbs a few seconds before the match was set to start, then waiting for the Bastions to walk in a straight line towards my position. I let go of the orbs then attempted to fire a Discord; from testing it multiple times the Discord orb always debuffed them after the orbs of destruction had hit the Bastion already.

If further research shows more technical info I will update this answer accordingly, but anecdotally from testing it the Discord orb is much slower than his regular orbs of destruction (although it does home in on enemies)

Comment: The speed of the discord orb has been boosted dramatically since, so it's worth running this test again.

Answer (score 1):

From Redditer SpriteGuy_000's [spread sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tb7xg_EmtkqgR7da6IDMcFjdEsFkefcW_78mAIRKp0w/edit#gid=1521377263), the travel speed for all of Zenyatta's orb.

- **Orb of Destruction**   66.66
- **Alt Fire** 66.66
- **Orb of Harmony**   26.66
- **Orb of Discord**   26.66

Therefore, Orb of Discord does not travel fast enough to apply to someone before your charged Orbs of Destruction.